# Access control for iOS App with Azure AD users

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I have an iOS app which is already in the app store, and i am authenticating users of my app through my web api. The app accessed by the users and this access given manually. In the next release i just want to control the access to my app with Azure AD i.e, the app get accessed by only users who are configured in the Azure AD.

I am new to Azure AD. I have gone through with multiple documents from Microsoft Azure started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started and all the docs/stuff confused me and i just came to know ADAL is the library which need to be used to get authenticated from Azure AD.

Please suggest me from where to start and what need to be followed/done. I have checked https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios and other related Azure native app libraries for objective-c.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question and list all items that confused you. Please try to be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Do you want to authenticate access to your app itself or provide an authenticated identity to your web service?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The question i posted is the end result i am expecting. The confusion is what exactly mobile server here is? 1) how could i implement to get my end result. 2) The above get started link shows creating new iOS app but how to implement for already existed app. 3)With cocoa pods damn errors/exception are rising so do we don't have other option without cocoa pods. 4) I just created an app in Azure AD(as shown in above get started link) what steps i need to follow for my expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to authenticate against Azure AD, you don't need any mobile backend - just the ADAL library and an appropriate configuration for a Native App in Azure AD.

Firstly, configure Azure AD for a Native Mobile App:

1. Log in to the Azure Classic Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com)
2. Select the appropriate directory from your list of all items
3. Click on the APPLICATIONS tab
4. Click on the ADD button at the bottom of the page
5. Click on Add an application my organization is developing
6. Give it a name, then select NATIVE CLIENT APPLICATION as the Type
7. Enter a valid URI for the redirect URI (it can be anything, but it has to be valid)
8. Click on the tick to create the application.

At this point, you've created the app.  Click on the CONFIGURE tab and note the Client ID and Redirect URI.

You can now use any of the samples by replacing the Client ID and the Redirect URI for the ADAL library.  Here is the relevant code from one of the samples:

```
- (void)acquireTokenInteractive:(id)sender
{
    ADTestAppSettings* settings = [ADTestAppSettings settings];
    NSString* authority = [settings authority];
    NSString* resource = [settings resource];
    NSString* clientId = [settings clientId];
    NSURL* redirectUri = [settings redirectUri];
    ADUserIdentifier* identifier = [self identifier];    
    ADCredentialsType credType = [self credType];

    BOOL validateAuthority = _validateAuthority.selectedSegmentIndex == 0;
    ADAuthenticationError* error = nil;
    ADAuthenticationContext* context = [[ADAuthenticationContext alloc
        initWithAuthority:authority
        validateAuthority:validateAuthority
        error:&error];

    if (!context)    
    {
        NSString* resultText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to create AuthenticationContext:\n%@", error];
        [_resultView setText:resultText];
        return;
    }

    [context setCredentialsType:credType];

    if ([self embeddedWebView])
    {
        [context setWebView:_webView];
        //[_authView setFrame:self.view.frame];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [_acquireSettingsView setHidden:YES];
            [_authView setHidden:NO];
        }];
    }

    __block BOOL fBlockHit = NO;

    [context acquireTokenWithResource:resource
                             clientId:clientId
                          redirectUri:redirectUri
                       promptBehavior:[self promptBehavior]
                       userIdentifier:identifier
                 extraQueryParameters:nil
                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result)
    {
        if (fBlockHit)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController 
                   alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                    message:@"Completion block was hit multiple times!"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
            });
            return;
        }
        fBlockHit = YES;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateResultView:result]; 
            [_webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body>done!</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
            [_authView setHidden:YES];
            [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ADTestAppCacheChangeNotification object:self];
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian.
Still i am in R&D of Azure and for understand i just done as of your steps here my question is we are not proving user details then which/how user it is going to authenticate.
could you please give an example of user authentication from Azure AD

Comment: The error i am getting:
status = AD_FAILED;
error = Error with code: AD_ERROR_UI_NO_MAIN_VIEW_CONTROLLER Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:The Application does not have a current ViewController. Inner error details: Error Domain=ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=401 "(null)"

Comment: Since you are internal to Azure, reach out to the Azure AD team directly.  You can also reach out to me internally, and I will point you in the right direction.